# how to prevent conflicts between publishing and subscribing in mosquitto?

Tags: php, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

The situation is,
I created an mqtt client using Mosquitto-alpha , in PHP scripting language.
so I have a subscribe function that runs infinitely to fetch data coming from a device every minute
e.g

Inside the Server I ran this
php /path/to/my/file/MyPHPscript subscribe &

In the client Device I have 2 services running every minute to publish data to the mqtt broker

```
e.g
* * * * * php /path/to/my/file/MyPHPScript publish dataA
* * * * * sleep 2; php /path/to/my/file/MyPHPScript publish dataB
```

if I don't put a sleep of 2 seconds to the 2nd service before running it, the supposedly two datas won't get publish together in the same minute. And then, if I add a subscribe  in the device to capture messages coming from the server, it will give intrmittent data push with the  two cron service

```
e.g  

    * * * * * php /path/to/my/file/MyPHPScript publish dataA
    * * * * * sleep 2; php /path/to/my/file/MyPHPScript publish dataB
```

on seperate terminal I ran this

```
php /path/to/my/file/MyPHPScript subscribe serverData &
```

this code above disturbs the data transmission of the other two cron services...is there a way to make these 3 work every minute without conflict ?

Comment: Edit the question to show the actual code. Most likely you are using the same client id so the second instance of the script is kicking the first off the broker before it finishes.

Comment: yeah i have fixed it already a few hours ago. thanks though

Comment: Then answer your own question or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by changing the client ids used by pub and sub commands